# PFImageView - How to clear cache?

Tags: swift, caching, parse-platform, pfimageview

I'm using PFImageViews a lot in my app, since I need its caching ability... The thing is, that my app now takes 108.9MBs of storage! Is there any way to free up this storage?

Comment: I always understood Parse automatically flushed the cache when it got too large.

Comment: And when does it get too large? Is there a way to clean it up myself, say once a week?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, in order to delete all cached images, we simply have to call:

```
PFFile.clearAllCachedDataInBackground()
```

Answer (score 1):

To manually clear the Parse query cache you can call (In Swift):

```
query.clearCachedResult()
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not talking about PFQuery caching... I'm talking about image caching, using the PFImageView subclass... Do you have any idea, if it's possible to clear that cache?